# Jackson UUID serialization issue

Tags: java, jackson

We are generating UUID for our objects, this UUID is converted to a BINARY(16) and stored in Mysql. We then query this value from the DB and convert it back to BINARY(36) the original UUID value.

Now in our API when this value is serialized to JSON the UUID is returned as a Base64 encoded string (JACKSON works this way). How do i get the original value instead of the Base64 encoded value?

Comment: Try to use the Same  Base64.jar to decrypt na if you know that process that it exactly encodes using Base64 encryption.We have Base64.decode() method in that jar

Comment: We query a big list of objects, dont want to iterate through each of them to base64 decode a single field. Is there a way to do this using a custom serializer just for that field? Dropwizard using Jackson mapper to output the objects as JSON.

Comment: I'd recommend transforming the UUID to a string and returning as a String in your JSON.